# Printing to WiFi printer android

Tags: java, android, printing, android-print-manager

I need to create an android application that sends data to multiple printers without any user input regarding printer selection.
Basically, when the user taps on some UI button the app should know to witch available printer(can be more than one) to send a printing request.

I know how to print using PrintManager, but I want to avoid showing the screen from PrintDocumentAdaper (print preview).

I have seen this question, but I didn't found a concrete answer on how to do it:
[I want to print automatically without user interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48578728/i-want-to-print-automatically-without-user-interaction)