# Background printing on Android MAUI app without showing the UI for printer selection

Tags: android, .net, xamarin.android, maui

All, I am working on a mobile app POC using .Net Maui where we have a requirement to print a page in background. I am able to write the platform specific code to print on Android, however whenever the print job is fired, the screen to select the printer pops up. I want to pass the default printer when printing the page and do not want the user to select the printer everytime, as there will be lot of printing involved in the process. We want the printing to be a background process without any user intervention.
I would like to know how to achieve this on .Net Maui Android mobile app using .Net Maui or otherwise.

I tried looking if there is way to pass the default printer when calling the print job on Android, but could not find any option.

Below is what I did so far

1. Created a partial class to print
2. In platform specific folder for Android, I added below code for printing

   ```
        Context context = Platform.CurrentActivity;

        Android.Webkit.WebView  webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(context);

        PrintManager printManager = context.GetSystemService(MainActivity.PrintService).JavaCast<PrintManager>();

        string htmlData = "test";
        webView.LoadData(htmlData, null, null);

        string jobName = "test";
        PrintAttributes printAttribute = new PrintAttributes.Builder()
                                            .SetMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.NaLetter)
                                            .Build();


        printManager.Print(jobName, webView.CreatePrintDocumentAdapter("test"), printAttribute);
   ```

Comment: please show the relevant code.

Comment: @Jason : I have updated the post to add the sample code

Comment: At the platform level, its simply Android code (though in c#). See if you can find ANY Android example (in any language) that solves this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48578728/i-want-to-print-automatically-without-user-interaction

Comment: My point is that there are many existing variations of your question that you should read for ideas.  https://www.google.com/search?q=android+print+without+user+interaction+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Jason : Thanks for sharing the link. I did research but could not find anything. Nonetheless, will keep working on it